# Can't install and use "draper" gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator, draper

I have some problems handling draper gem.

1. install draper
       gem 'draper'

   ```
   $ bundle install
   ```

and this was successful.

2. did `rails generate draper:install`

   ```
   $ rails generate draper:install
   ```

but I got some errors

```
    Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
    Expected string default value for '--helper'; got true (boolean)
    Expected string default value for '--assets'; got true (boolean)
    Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
    Expected string default value for '--helper'; got true (boolean)
    Expected string default value for '--decorator'; got true (boolean)
    Expected string default value for '--decorator'; got true (boolean)
    Expected string default value for '--jbuilder'; got true (boolean)
    Could not find generator draper:install.
```

3. never mind, I did `rails generate decorator Service`

   ```
   Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
   Expected string default value for '--helper'; got true (boolean)
   Expected string default value for '--assets'; got true (boolean)
   Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
   Expected string default value for '--helper'; got true (boolean)
   Expected string default value for '--decorator'; got true (boolean)
   Expected string default value for '--decorator'; got true (boolean)
   Expected string default value for '--jbuilder'; got true (boolean)
   Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
         create  app/decorators/service_decorator.rb
   ```

this was successful.

4. made method in services_decorator

   ```
   class ServiceDecorator < Draper::Decorator
     delegate_all

     def hello
       'hello'
     end
   end
   ```
5. call this method from view

   ```
   <%= Service.first.decorate.hello %>
   ```

but this was error,

```
    Could not infer a decorator for ActiveRecord::Base.
```

Can someone teach me what was wrong and how to solve this problem?
The rails version is 4.1.7, and draper version is 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove errors while using rails generator change `gem thor` version to 0.19.1

And try to add to `application.rb`

`config.autoload.path += %W(#{config.root}/app/decorators)`

Comment: This didn't work for me in Rails 5.1 — I needed to use `config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path('/app/decorators', __dir__)` instead.